# Adding returned value to a list in recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am learning recursion, I am having trouble in storing the returned value intermediate recursive calls

Here is the reference code:

```
def func(n, ans,res):
    if n <=1:
        print(ans)
        return ans
    for i in range(2,9):
        if n % i == 0:
            func(n//i,ans+str(i),res)
    return res
print (func(98, '',[]))
```

The output of the code is:

```
277
727
772
```

I want the output to be stored in the res list, ie. the output should be `[277,727,772]`, I don't want to use any global variable or class. Please suggest any way of doing it.

Comment: what happened when you tried to just add `res.append(ans)`? python lists are passed by reference. So you even if you append recursively after the recursive function call, the list will be modified.

Answer (score 1):

A basic problem is that you call `func(n//i,ans+str(i),res)` which returns a value, but you ignore that retuned value. In this case, there isn't really any value in having the extra argument in the function. Just collect the items from your loop and return those.

For example:

```
def func(n, ans):
    if n <=1:
        return [ans]
    res = []
    for i in range(2,9):
        if n % i == 0:
            res.extend(func(n//i, ans+str(i)))
    return res

print(func(98, ''))
# ['277', '727', '772']
```

In python these kind of things can often be cleaner with a generator where you defer making the list. This can also be more memory efficient because you can iterate over the items without making the list at all:

```
def func(n, ans):
    if n <=1:
        yield ans
        return 
    for i in range(2,9):
        if n % i == 0:
            yield from func(n//i, ans+str(i))

print(list(func(98, '')))
#['277', '727', '772']
```

**Edit based on comment:**
If you want to store the state in the argument, one way would be to append it in the base case and then return it after the recursion unwinds:

```
def func(n, ans, res):
    if n <=1:
        res.append(ans)
    else:
        for i in range(2,9):
            if n % i == 0: 
                func(n // i, ans+str(i), res)

    return res

s = []
print (func(98, '', s))
# ['277', '727', '772']

# s has been mutated to this values as well
print(s)
# ['277', '727', '772']
```

Comment: This answers this question, thanks a lot for this. But in case if want to push the returned value to heap or other data structure then how will we approach the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would restructure this to run as a generator. This will make it easy to return multiple values. This will also allow you to get rid of the response list. You also don't need to pass down the current answer. It can be constructed on the fly.

Example:

```
def func(n):
    if n <= 1:
        yield ''
        return

    for i in range(2,9):
        if n % i == 0:
            for ans in func(n // i):
                yield str(i) + ans


print(list(func(98)))
```

```
['277', '727', '772']
```

Also rather than returning a string, a list of ints might be easier to work with:

```
def func(n):
    if n <= 1:
        yield []
        return

    for i in range(2,9):
        if n % i == 0:
            for ans in func(n // i):
                yield [i, *ans]


print(list(func(98)))
```

```
[[2, 7, 7], [7, 2, 7], [7, 7, 2]]
```

Comment: This answers this question, thanks a lot for this. But in case if want to push the returned value to heap or other data structure then how will we approach the problem?

Comment: @Dr_Doggo not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate your use-case?

Comment: When I asked this question, I was curious to know how could I append the returned value of intermediate recursive calls to a list and return back the whole list. You all guys solved the problem but didn't use standard list operation like append. If the question would be related to heap, and I wanted to heappush the returned value to the heap instead of list, how could I have done that

Answer (score 0):

The way the code was initially set up is acting almost redundant, because sure the print statements are running, but you have the line:

```
func(n//i,ans+str(i),res)
```

which is being used as an object with no return type, but then later it is used like:

```
print (func(98, '',[]))
```

which treats it like it returns a string, which is ans.

The only way I could see to make it work as self containing code (no global variable) that would generate a list, is to make it a generator like in the following code:

```
def func(n, ans):
    if n <=1:
        yield ans
    else:
        for i in range(2,9):
            if n % i == 0:
                for j in func(n//i,ans+str(i)):
                    yield j

new_list = list(func(98, '')
print(new_list)
```

In this code, it essentially returns each item of the list as it is coming across it, as opposed to trying to carry all the values across each stack of the function.